# JSON.NET Deserialize nameless attributes with nested object

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I've the following JSON:

```
{
    seq:108,
    d: 
    {
        s:'0',
        p:0,
        st:'ftt',
        time:153
    },
    h:[
        [287720,'James J.',0],
        [54421,'Martin M.',0],
        [54028,'Sara S.',0]
      ],
    e:[
        [2,9,252223,'Raul B.',4,{d:85124}],
        [2,28,287748,'Luis Y.',2,{}],
        [1,32,287746,'Ramiro L.',2,{}],
        [1,41,287719,'Franco T.',2,{}],
        [1,51,12295,'Marcos G.',4,{d:287746}],
        [1,57,287715,'Michael O\'Neal C.',4,{d:48191}]
      ]
}
```

And I've following classes to deserialize this JSON:

```
public class SModel
{
    public string seq { get; set; }
    public DModel d { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> h { get; set; }
    //public List<List<string>> e { get; set; }
}

public class DModel
{
    public string s { get; set; }
    public string p { get; set; }
    public string st { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting problem deserializing "e" in JSON. It's `List<List<T>>` and each T has and object in it. I need some guidance to write my classes to deserialize this JSON.

Comment: Why don't use `public List<List<object>> e {get;set;}` instead?

Comment: It worked. It feels silly sometimes how I couldn't get there. Please post your answer so that I can mark it as answer and up-vote it :)

Comment: Sometimes it's really helpful if you read your own problem *"each T has an object in it".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is change the `public List<List<string>> e {get; set;}` to object

For Example:

```
public List<List<object>> e { get; set; }
```